# Wordpress + Flatsome Theme Appearance Display Limitation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

Using the Flatsome theme I have a few questions and would like to try and get them solved myself, is this the manner in which I should direct those questions?

I'm running WooCommerce I'd simply like to know how to make the breadcrumbs bar a little smaller where it displays the name.. on the single product page it looks great but I see no settings to edit it on the display list, i can show you a screenshot of the problem here (ALSO I WANT TO CHANGE THE WHITE BACKGROUD WHERE IT SAYS "HEADSHOP" TO SOMETHING MORE MATCHING) -- THERE ARE NO OPTIONS FOR CHANGING ANY OF THIS?

[image]

I'd really like to be able to edit this area and I'd like to gain  more access to it, this theme appearance editor area wont let me do it, I've tried and tried to no avail!

With that being said, this is just the display of all the main products.. What throws me off is that in the Single Product page it formats exactly the way I want it to on all pages, see example here..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not an expert but I suggest you to put the URL of your website as minimum, because is going to be difficult to help you without [what you have tried or the code of your website](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Following with the question, you can reduce the height of the container using some CSS. By default both margins (in this case the padding) are in 20px, so i just reduce them to 0.

```
.featured-title .page-title-inner {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.page-title-inner {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 0px;
    min-height: 60px;
}
```

This is how it looks with the modifications in the margins. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7KX7.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMmNd.jpg

But still, I don't understand what it's keeping the text so high in the container.

To change the background color of that button, you can modifiy the CSS Property.

```
.nav-tabs > li.active > a {
    background-color: red;
}
```

This is how it looks. 
[image]

So you just need to put that CSS in your theme. 
If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as an Answer.

Comment: Yes perhaps we could speak in private and see if you could look at it? It is confusing me to no end! I have been at it for hours

Comment: We are in contact right now, so I dont' see it necesary to be in private. This is a public forum so other people can see this answer if they have a similar problem.
I just look at it with the URL in your profile, thats why you need to update your question  to provide more info and if you have tried the code in my answer

Comment: I did some editing and I have another question for you I haven't added the code yet because im unsure how... but somewhere in my fooling around i messed up how the image background is displayed.... see the red lines i have added.... it wasnt repeating the image before, so i changed it to another and it's still trying to repeat it???

Comment: DUDE, you are a genius... could I possibly come to you for help in the future? You obviously know your stuff!

Comment: I still need to know why https://i.imgur.com/It4yNcc.png isn't displaying the full image, instead a contained one..... it was never doing that before

Comment: I suppose I just need to enlarge the image... perhaps it's been doing that all along and I never noticed it, however your code worked great... You must have alot of experience with Flatsome

Comment: Glad my answer helped you. Im new so If it is within my abilities i will be glad to help. By the way, i dont understand your question, the image of the birds isn't displaying correctly? Could it be its because the image "try" to fit itself with the other containers (text, padding etc). Anyway, you can ask more questions as you see fit, that's why the community is here.

Comment: I figured it out.. I had to enlarge the header background image, it was trying to tile... Ok so, seeing as you helped me with the color in the navigation.. I turned it purple, but do you figure there would be a cleaner way of doing it... I was thinking maybe an image would work but then again I'm not sure what would be best https://i.imgur.com/3CX923D.jpg -- it just looks boxxy and plain, if only i could just make it a little less flat --- then again the theme is called flatsome lol

Comment: A cleaner way to do that, is by using the options that the theme provide. There must be an option in the theme that let you change all the style in the template without using code. That is because flatsome is a premium theme.